# Writing/Reading files on Windows Shared Folder from ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app running in docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application which is running fine in IIS on a Windows Server 2016 machine.

Recently my Company decided to move all apps to docker on linux.

I've got most of the application running fine on this new environment, but I'm still having an issue with one of the application features.

It used to read/write files to shared folders (Format `\\Servername\\FolderName\\FileName.xlsx` for example).

The first time I tried it seemed to work, but it actually saved the file in a folder on the container, so was lost after a restart.

For now the overlay they've put on top of docker does not really allow me to mount the shared folders on the host to save my files there, so I wanted to know if there was a way to do it within my application code.

I've tried the solutions explained here:
https://coderjony.com/blogs/mount-a-windows-share-on-linux-container-using-cnet

I adapted to include domain, but I got an access denied, and I don't know if it's the container folder that's denied or the shared folder, the message is not very verbose.

Thanks

Comment: "For now the overlay .. does not really allow me to mount the shared folders". Could you clarify this. What stops you from connecting the share on the docker-host machine and then bind it as a volume to your container?

Comment: @SanchoPanza I don't have access to the host. Essentially they have automated github actions that pull my code, including my Dockerfile, build the image and run it. We can submit some configurations files that pass some parameters to the docker command, but for now it doesn't seem to support mounting smb shares.

Comment: Adding on my comment above, this is why I was lookign for a .net side solution: I wanted to find a way to open a file stream to a windows share from the container and wirte to it for example.